# Need help sql query for report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got report table as below : Report(StudentName, SubJectName, Mark) and example data below

```
StudentName    |    SubjectName   |  Mark
Tommy               A                6
Tommy               B                8
Tommy               C                10
Susan               A                7
Susan               B                10
```

So I'd like to query and display As below:

```
SubjectName  | A | B |  C
Tommy          6   8    10
Susan          7   10   0
```

Could you suggest me how to do this?. I researched using pivot but I don't know how to apply?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` statement

```
select studentname,
max(case when subjectname='A' then mark else 0 end) 'A',
max(case when subjectname='B' then mark else 0 end) 'B',
max(case when subjectname='C' then mark else 0 end) 'C'
from table1
group by studentname
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6330/3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a pivot,

```
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
ORDER BY PRODUCT
GO
```

See example : [SQL Pivot](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used pivot SQL and my problem was solved. 
Below is my query

```
SELECT StudentName, A, B, ISNULL(C,0) as C
FROM (select StudentName, subjectName, Mark from dbo.Student) as src
Pivot(max(mark) for subjectName in(A, B, C))  as pvt
```

and also below is more example about pivot
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01e1c/2)